# MultiPolygon column by migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, polygon, postgis

I'm trying to change my `polygon` column type to a `multipolygon` column type.

My code is a simple line.

```
change_column :messages, :area_shape, :multipolygon, srid: 3785
```

But `Postgres` doesn't know this type. I thought that I missed something on my `PostGIS` configuration but I can't see it.

This my exact error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "multipolygon" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "messages" ALTER COLUMN "area_shape" TYPE multipolygon
```

This is how I've created my `area_shape` as a `polygon` type:

```
add_column :messages, :area_shape, :polygon, srid: 3785
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid, that you mixed up postgres' own `polygon` type (first link), with postgis' `geometry` type (second link). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-geometric.html    http://postgis.net/docs/geometry.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I had to remove then recreate my column:

```
remove_column :messages, :area_shape
add_column :messages, :area_shape, :multi_polygon, srid: 3785
```

I think I can now understand why it's not possible. Indeed, it seems difficult to change a `polygon` type to a `multi_polygon` type without losing data logique.

If you really need to change the type, you can use what was said by @Mike (manually) and create a small method to convert `polygon` to `multi_polygon` but it's not really safe in my mind. 
Tip: a `multi_polygon` type is an `Enumerable` that means `multi_polygon` accepts `Array` type.

Comment: Had the same issue. Strange that it says the type does not exist instead of saying it can't be converted.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how `RGeo` attempts to implement `change_column` (is there documentation for it?), but it isn't correct since there is no such `multipolygon` type.

If you have direct access to PostgreSQL, following from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28878/1872), use this DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ALTER COLUMN area_shape TYPE geometry(MultiPolygon,3785)
    USING ST_Multi(area_shape);
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you ! By the way I really need to use a migration because I can do that on my development environment but for a production one, I can't. I'll try to find a solution of this migration and I'll add the solution here if I find some.